# No EditText view is clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I've spent a bunch of time experimenting and I can't get this working. Any type of edit text that I add to my linear layout, cannot be clicked. The weird part is it looks focused (which I put in my code).
I've been unable to get even the keyboard to pop up, the wierd part is if I hide it and make visible a spinner with the same attributes - the spinner's popup works.
Note: below it is AutocomletetextBox, but when it was just EditTextBox and I commented out - the adapter stuff. Still didn't work, didn't even pop up the keyboard.

[image]

Here's my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="com.example.edu.testversion.activity.CategoryChooser"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="90dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_start_map"
            android:id="@+id/play_game_button"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/game_spinner"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:text="Which way do you want to play the game?"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/get_started_dialog"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="20dip"
            android:id="@+id/restaurant_name_display"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />


        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:completionThreshold="3"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:id="@+id/find_location_dropdown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:minWidth="160dip"/>
        <!--android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />
        -->


    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="416dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_weight="3.25" />
```

And the only code that touches it is in my oncreate:

```
mAutocompleteLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.find_location_dropdown);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,androidBooks);
        mAutocompleteLocation.setThreshold(3);
        mAutocompleteLocation.setAdapter(adapter);
        mAutocompleteLocation.setCompletionHint("FUN!");
        mAutocompleteLocation.setFocusable(true);
        mAutocompleteLocation.setClickable(true);
        mAutocompleteLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Please fix your xml code. There are errors and your screenshot is not really the same with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line in autocompletiontextview everything works fine

```
 android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Comment: Thank you! Why is it that textIsSelectable makes it not work? What is it's function?

Comment: it may have something to do with that property overriding gesture inputs, that's why when you click on it, it doesn't respond. you don't need it though, it's only used for TextViews. You can select EditText content simply by long press.